# Creating a simple line chart from a CSV using D3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am trying to create a basic line chart using values from a csv file through D3.js. My csv file is set up as such:

```
Date, Value
1/1/2015, 1
1/2/2015, 2
```

and this is my JavaScript:

```
<script>
    d3.csv("data/values.csv", function (data) {

        var canvas = d3.select("p").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 500);

        var group = canvas.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(100, 100)");

        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function (d) { return d.Date; })
            .y(function (d) { return d.Value; });   

        group.selectAll("path")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
                .attr("d", line)
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("stroke-width", 10);  
    });
</script>
```

However, i get nothing on my webpage. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The d3 `svg.line` component has expects you to provide functions for the `x` and `y` values that returns numbers. In your case, the `x` function is returning a date:

```
    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) { return d.Date; })
        .y(function (d) { return d.Value; });
```

Typically you will want to use scales to convert these numbers from your data coordinate system to the screen coordinate system.

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Date; }));
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Value; }));

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.Date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.Value); });
```

See this complete example:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245